# White space remover script don't work on email input

Tags: javascript

I have a script that works amazingly how I want it to work, it basically prevents a user from adding a white space in the beginning of all the inputs in

section 1 AKA the red section. This works on all types of inputs except the email input so how can I get this to also work with the email input as well? Here is my code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){

var trigger= document.querySelectorAll('#section-1 input');

 for(var i = 0; i < trigger.length; i++) {
   trigger[i].addEventListener('input',noStartingWhiteSpace);
 }

function noStartingWhiteSpace(e){
  var preventWhiteSpaceInput= e.target.value;
  if(/^\s/.test(preventWhiteSpaceInput))
    e.target.value = '';
}

});
```

```css
#section-1{
  background-color: red;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#section-1 input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#section-2{
  background-color: blue;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#section-2 input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#section-3{
  background-color: lime;
  width: 350px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#section-3 input{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<br>
<div id='section-1'>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='email' placeholder='Email'>
<br>
<input type='tel'>
</div><!--</section-1>-->

<div id='section-2'>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
</div><!--</section-2>-->

<div id='section-3'>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
<br>
<input type='text'>
</div><!--</section-3>-->
```

Comment: I cannot put aspace on the first character of e-mail, looks likes this works.

Comment: Yeah? That's strange I tested this on other computers and it produce the same result perhaps its your browser that your using?

Comment: Might be - firefox.

Comment: You are correct I tested this on another browser like internet explorer and it worked but other browsers it don't work :-(

Comment: Which browsers does it not work on? Probably worth listing as solutions might be specific to those.

Comment: My edge keeps crashing so I can't test that.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `input` element with type `email` as `<input type='email' />` then any trailing and leading whitespace is removed from each address in the list. If you use multiple emails for that `input` field then it should use comma separated values. This means that the leading and trailing whitespaces are invalid for `email` type. Hence `e.target.value` is always `''` no matter how much there are leading whitespace. So, the condition `/^\s/.test(preventWhiteSpaceInput)` result in `false` value.

To work around, you can set the type to `text` for the `input` with `email` type and when you submit the form or manipulate further check for the valid email value using regular expression for email.

For further reading on `input` with type `email` go through the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#Value)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this works in internet explorer but other browsers it don't work. I don't mind using the text input as a email the thing is that it will be nice to be able to do this with the email type so I can use it with mobile phones because mobile phones will bring up the right characters when the keyboard shows up.

Comment: @fsofb ` this works in internet explorer` because IE has old version of Javascript

Comment: Yeah i'm aware of that now i'm just curious in finding a way now how to get the same effect? To bad not all browsers treat code the same XP

Comment: I wonder if any one knows a unexpected method in getting this to work with the email type. I'm ma keep googling hopefully some one will surprise me.

Comment: @fsofb it is hard to find a fix like you need